# How can I display PDF file in java GUI application?

Tags: java, user-interface, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating online help in Java Swing application - using pdf user docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141504/creating-online-help-in-java-swing-application-using-pdf-user-docs)
>   [Opening a PDF in a desktop application in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221366/opening-a-pdf-in-a-desktop-application-in-java)

I want to add pdf file in GUI form and want to navigate up and down in pdf file. I am using J2SE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286867/java-pdf-viewer-with-fdf may  give you some options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should suit your requirements: http://www.icepdf.org/